# "Please try enabling Per-user Redirection" with CMake and VS19

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I try to build [SRT](https://github.com/Haivision/srt/tree/v1.4.0) with CMake on Windows 10 using VS2019 as generator.

[image: CMAKE]

Thru the `Configure` step, I have:

> The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.23.28106.4   The CXX compiler
>   identification is MSVC 19.23.28106.4   Check for working C compiler:
>   C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
>   Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/x86/cl.exe
>   Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
>   Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/x86/cl.exe
>   -- broken   CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60
>   (message):     The C compiler
>       "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/x86/cl.exe"
>   is not able to compile a simple test program.     It fails with the
>   following output:
>
> ```
> Change Dir: C:/Users/MLUser/Desktop/SRT/srt-1.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp  
> Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe
> ```
>
> cmTC_3ea98.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=Win32
>   /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version
>   16.3.1+1def00d3d for .NET Framework
>       Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>             Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.23.28106.4 for x86
>         testCCompiler.c
>         Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>         cl /c /I./MIDL /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /MP /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _LOCAL_NODE
>   /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t   /Zc:forScope
>   /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_3ea98.dir\Debug\"
>   /Fd"cmTC_3ea98.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze-
>   /errorReport:queue
>   "C:\Users\MLUser\Desktop\SRT\srt-1.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c"
>
> ```
>   cmTC_3ea98.vcxproj -> C:\Users\MLUser\Desktop\SRT\srt-1.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_3ea98.exe
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1992,5):
> ```
>
> warning MSB3073: The command
>   ""C:\Users\MLUser\Desktop\SRT\srt-1.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_3ea98.exe"
>   /RegServer" exited with code 1.
>   [C:\Users\MLUser\Desktop\SRT\srt-1.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_3ea98.vcxproj]
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1998,5):
> ```
>
> error MSB8011: Failed to register output. Please try enabling Per-user
>   Redirection or register the component from a command prompt with
>   elevated permissions.
>   [C:\Users\MLUser\Desktop\SRT\srt-1.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_3ea98.vcxproj]
>   CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.   Call
>   Stack (most recent call first):     CMakeLists.txt:15 (project)

**UPD**

I tried to launch Cmake GUI both with admin and no admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I see that I had custom properties in: `C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0`.
It `*.props` files where it was configured to register output.
I removed them, and passed "output redirection" issue.